# Generating Number on the base of Alphabetic Order

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I am trying to write a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008, which should generate ID number on the basis of another column's first letter like below:

[image: Auto Generation of ID alphabetically]

I am using SQL Server 2008. Would be grateful on any help. Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So `A`'s are all `1XXXX`, `B`'s `2XXXX` through `Z`'s `26XXXX`. Try this:

```
SELECT
        10000 * ( ASCII(LEFT(Field2, 1)) - 64 )
        + ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY LEFT(Field2, 1) ORDER BY Field2 ) Field1
        ,Field2
    FROM
        ( VALUES ( 'Alpha Company'), ( 'Airborn Company'), ( 'Bravo Company'),
        ( 'Charlie Company'), ( 'Cake Company'), ( 'Camel Company'),
        ( 'Delta Company'), ( 'Zeta Company') ) A ( Field2 ); 


Field1               Field2
-------------------- ---------------
10001                Airborn Company
10002                Alpha Company
20001                Bravo Company
30001                Cake Company
30002                Camel Company
30003                Charlie Company
40001                Delta Company
260001               Zeta Company
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, It is what  I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `rank` window function to generate these IDs:

```
SELECT 10000 + RANK() OVER (ORDER BY field2 ASC) as field1, field2
FROM   my_table
```

EDIT:
I misunderstood the question. You need a separate ranking for the first letter and the entire name:

```
SELECT 10000 *
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(field2, 1) ORDER BY field2 ASC) + 
       RANK() OVER (ORDER BY field2 ASC) as field1, 
       field2
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it is fixed, however I want to generate a number which should be corresponding to the Rank of Alphabet order, like if the Word starts with "A" the Id should start with 1, if Word starts with "B" Id should start with 2, and so on.

Comment: @JamshaidRiaz I misunderstood the question then. See my edited answer, it should produce the output you want.